# Invoke method, Converting

Tags: c#

I'm new here. I have a question for you, maybe just easy, but I can't do it well. I have a few fields in my class:

```
public Player player;
public Run run;
```

And a code:

```
    public void doit(string method)
    {          
        foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            foreach (var meth in prop.FieldType.GetMethods())
            {
                if (meth.Name == method)
                {
                    meth.Invoke(prop, null);
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I'm trying to run this problem, I have a error while running:

> Object does not match target type.

In line:

```
meth.Invoke(prop, null);
```

Error appears, because "prop" isn't an Class object.

When i'm trying to do this:

```
Player testPlayer;
testPlayer = prop;
```

I have an error:

> 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' to 'WindowsFormsApplication.Player'

I tried many things, but nothing work.
Can you help me plz? It's important for me :)

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe example inputs/outputs would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to invoke the method passing in the actual `FieldInfo` object, rather than the *value* of the field.

A simple fix would be:

```
if (meth.Name == method)
{
    meth.Invoke(prop.GetValue(this), null);
}
```

However, if you're trying to find a method by name, there's an easier way:

```
public void doit(string method)
{          
    foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        // Get the method by name
        var meth = prop.FieldType.GetMethod(method);
        if (meth != null)
        {
            meth.Invoke(prop.GetValue(this), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hahaha!
I known it is easy!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to get the *value* of that property:

```
meth.Invoke(prop.GetValue(this), null);
```